# angular-generator with susy and breakpoint

Tags: susy-compass, breakpoint-sass, yeoman-generator-angular

I am trying to setup an angular app using Susy and Breakpoint instead of bootstrap.

I am using yeoman to run angular-generator. During the install, instead of saying Yes to bootstrap, i say No. This all goes well and my app runs in the browser fine with 'grunt serve'.

Next i run: **bower install susy** and **bower install breakpoint** - both install fine and i can see them in the bower_components folder.

I then import them by manually adding @import reference to main.scss like this:

```
// bower:scss
@import "../bower_components/susy/sass/_susy.scss";
@import "../bower_components/breakpoint/breakpoint/_breakpoint.scss";
// endbower
```

And also in the Gruntfile.js i have added **require: 'susy'** to compass like so:

```
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
    generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
    httpImagesPath: '/images',
    httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
    httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
    relativeAssets: false,
    assetCacheBuster: false,
    raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n',
    **require: 'susy'**
  },
```

As outlined on the susy website: http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/

Ok, that's all well and good, but here's the problem.. because i have manually adding them to my main.scss file, everytime i stop and start the app, it deletes the **@import** references in my SCSS file. i don't know how to add them dynamically / or properly to the gruntfile.js so that they get compiled and saved permenantly.  Each time i stop and start grunt, both imports are removed from main.scss leaving me with this:

```
// bower:scss
// end bower
```

Has anyone else had this same problem, if so what's the solution? 
Any help would be appreciated.

thanks
~declan

Comment: ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `@import` statements outside of the bower comments.  So, instead of:

```
// bower:scss
@import "../bower_components/susy/sass/_susy.scss";
@import "../bower_components/breakpoint/breakpoint/_breakpoint.scss";
// endbower
```

try:

```
// bower:scss
// endbower
@import "../bower_components/susy/sass/_susy.scss";
@import "../bower_components/breakpoint/breakpoint/_breakpoint.scss";
```

That worked for me.